# Angularjs ngSwitch with static nodes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I have some common nodes in an ngSwitch?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="widget in widgets" ng-switch="" on="widget.foo">
     <h1>Test</h1>
     <p ng-switch-when="bar">Lorem ipsum</p>
     <small ng-switch-when="baz">Lorem ipsum</small>
     <footer>common footer</footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcabnettek/FmdWn/1/)

The switch element renders as the last child of the template. Any ideas if there is a better way?

Comment: This is actually a shortcoming (or even a bug) of `ng-switch` that has [been patched](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e88d6179c3a6a137e75fa09de906fc83c6515db2). In order to take advantage of the patch, you'll need to use Angular 1.1.4, 1.1.5 or 1.2.0. Otherwise, you'll need to wrap your switch cases like Michael Benford has done in his answer.

Comment: yes I noticed that. What is the difference between using a stable vs. unstable build? We have stuck to the stable releases since day one. We're terrified of the word "unstable" lol.

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with the Angular team's release model, but usually "unstable" means that any new features or API changes are not "final" and are subject to change, whereas in a "stable" build APIs are guaranteed to work as advertised. It has less to do with untested/buggy code than you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="widget in widgets">
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <div ng-switch on="widget.foo">
          <p ng-switch-when="bar">Lorem ipsum</p>
          <small ng-switch-when="baz">Lorem ipsum</small>
      </div>
      <footer>common footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FmdWn/2/).

Comment: yes that's what i figured, I just hate getting the extra useless div element. Thank you though for a valid solution. =)